# I want to open foo.MYI foo.MYD foo.frm db.opt in MySQL 8.0 with MyISAM engine

Tags: mysql, myisam

I cannot open foo.MYI foo.MYD foo.frm db.opt extension files with MySQL 8.0.

I downloaded database folders but I cannot open them in MySQL Community Workbench. I tried lots of ways like create table with parameter ENGINE=MyISAM and copy database folders but I cannot achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db.opt` file, `*.frm` files, and other metadata files are no longer used, because MySQL 8.0 implements metadata in a different way.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-dictionary-file-removal.html

> The metadata files listed below are removed from MySQL. Unless
> otherwise noted, data previously stored in metadata files is now
> stored in data dictionary tables.
>
> ...
>
> - db.opt files: Database configuration files. These files, one per database directory, contained database default character set attributes.

You shouldn't move MyISAM files around as a means of importing data. Use a SQL dump and restore process.